# AngularJS binding between variables

Tags: javascript, data-binding, angularjs

I've got a list of users which I retrieve from my service. When I select any user I can see and edit info *(email, roles, etc)*. The problem is that I don't want these changes to affect user's data in the list, I want to update data only after saving (clicking a button).

Now I'm using two variables:

`$scope.selected` -  currently selected user
`$scope.editable` - variable for storing the data I'm editing

And I exchange data like this:

```
$scope.initEditable = function () 
{
    $scope.editable = {};
    $.extend($scope.editable, $scope.selected);
}
```

Looks like a terrible solution. What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, this is the Angular-way of approaching this problem, you are on the right track. In scenarios like yours one would typically:

- Copy an item upon selection (edit start) - this is what you do with `editable`
- Have 2-way data binding changing a copy (or an original element)
- Upon edit completion we can propagate changes from a copy to the original

The nice things about this pattern is that we can easily:

- Offer the 'cancel' functionality where users can revert their changes
- Be able to compare a copy and the original and drive parts of the UI based on this comparison (for example, we could disable a 'Save' button if there were no changes)

So, I don't think at all that this approach is terrible. The only suggestion I could have is to use angular's `angular.copy` [method](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy) instead of `$.extend`.

Comment: To automate that stuff I've created **lazy-model** directive https://github.com/vitalets/lazy-model